# How to render Chart via Ajax request?

Tags: c#, ajax, image, asp.net-mvc-4, charts

***Controller:***

```
public FileResult CreateChart()
{
        Chart chart = new Chart
        {
            ImageType = ChartImageType.Jpeg,
            ImageStorageMode = ImageStorageMode.UseImageLocation,
            Width = new Unit(600),
            Height = new Unit(400)
        };
        chart.Series.Add("Years");
        chart.Series.Add("Months");
        chart.Legends.Add("Test");
        Series seriesDetail = new Series
        {
            Name = "Result Chart",
            IsValueShownAsLabel = false,
            Color = Color.FromArgb(198, 99, 99),
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar,
            BorderWidth = 2
        };

        foreach (var result in CurrentMember.Section.Filters)
        {
            DataPoint point = new DataPoint
            {
                AxisLabel = result.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                YValues = new[] { double.Parse(result.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) }
            };
            seriesDetail.Points.Add(point);
        }
        seriesDetail.ChartArea = "Result Chart";

        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
        return new FileContentResult(ms.GetBuffer(), @"image/png");

}
```

***Partial View:***

***Main View:***

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Press me","CreateChart", "Reports",new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "dataTable"
    })

<div style="overflow-x: auto; direction: rtl; overflow-x: auto;" id="dataTable">

</div>
```

***Ajax Request:***

```
 $('div#dataTable').load('/reports/createchart/', 
   function(html) {
       $("#imgHistoryChart")[0].src = "/reports/createchart/";

   });
```

***Result:***

```
�PNG  IHDRX�r5�sRGB���gAMA���a pHYs���o�d�IDATx^��1à�7ݙ� *��,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�b�,��`� &X1�� @L�R���4��$ߡIEND�B`�
```

Question: How to fix it, that I would be able to see Image and no this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using an AJAX link? What's the point? A simple anchor would do the job just fine:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Press me", "CreateChart", "Reports", null, new { id = "showChart" })
```

and then in a separate javascript file subscribe to the click handler and point the `src` attribute of your `<img>` element where you want the chart to be displayed to your controller action:

```
$(function() {
    $('#showChart').click(function() {
        $('#imgHistoryChart').attr('src', this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also you haven't shown what this `imgHistoryChart` is but it should be an `<img>` element.

Comment: I recieve ÿØÿàJFIF``ÿÛC    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀX"ÿÄ ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á #3RðbrÑ $4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ?÷ú(¢€ (¢€

Comment: Where do you receive that? When the link is clicked? Did you see the javascript I included in my answer which subscribes to the .click event of the anchor and sets the src property of the image? Is this script working? Did you include jQuery?

Comment: Any javascript errors in your console? Is the .click handler executed?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. Is the .click handler executed? Do you get errors in the javascript console? Try calling this controller action directly and store the result to an image file on your disk to see if you can open it.

Comment: I have tested your script and it doesn't do what I've asked for.
It's return me an image on the other page.

Comment: What other page? I really don't understand. Could you explain in details what exactly are you trying to achieve? I thought you wanted to display the image when some link is clicked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31922/discussion-between-iamstalker-and-darin-dimitrov)